# Backbone js: Not getting data from model while fetching data using rest api in collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

```
 //Declare model
app.models.Items =Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        id: '',
        name : ''
    }
});

//fetch data using collection
app.models.ItemsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: app.models.Items,
    url: urlprefix + id + "/items",
});

//Create Instance of Collection
app.models.ItemsModel = new app.models.ItemsCollection();
app.models.ItemsModel.fetch({
    async: false,
    // in success get response and add response in model
    success: function(response) {
        for (i = 0 ;i < response.models[0].attributes.elements.length;i++){
            app.models.ItemsModel.add(new app.models.Items(response.models[0].attributes.elements[i]));
        }
    },
    error: function (errorResponse) {
        console.log(errorResponse);
    }
});
```

In controller i have to set new property in my model but i dont have 
get model. in console i tried item.models[0] to fetch a first model but it show 
me undefined.

```
var item = new app.models.Items();

item.set("Id", 'TG');
item.set("name", 'Gokul');
item.save(null, {
    success: function(model, response){
        console.log("save");
    },
    error: function(error, response){
        console.log("Error: while saving Account data:" +JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
```

I am new in backbone.js so, please help me. if i did anything wrong in my code

Comment: Did you try viewing the response in the chrome debugger to ensure you got a good/valid response?

Answer (score -1):

There are several issues here:

1. There is no async: false option when calling fetch on a collection. When you call fetch(), an asynchronous call is made to the server to get the results. You wouldn't want your browser to hang while that happens.
2. You don't need to set the individual models in the collection. Backbone does that for you, assuming your REST endpoint is returning valid JSON.

   I would get rid of the for loop in your success method. You don't need to do that.

   If necessary, you can override the parse option in your Model definition to handle custom processing of the response for each Model.
3. You also want to set the urlRoot on your Model definition so you can use the model outside of the collection as you did.
4. Finally, it looks like you have the url property on your collection set incorrectly. You don't want the *id* in there.

All told, your code should look something like the following:

```
app.models.Items =Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: urlprefix + '/items',

    defaults: {
        id: '',
        name : ''
     },

    parse: function(response, options) {
        //your custom code here if necessary
    }
});

app.models.ItemsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: app.models.Items,
    url: urlprefix + "/items",
});
```

That's it. Then you can create a collection and fetch the current items:

```
var items = new app.models.ItemsCollection();
items.fetch();
```

But remember, that fetch() is an asynchronous method. You have to wait for the results to come back from the server before you can expect any items in the collection. That's what the success option is for.

And, you can now create an item independently, as you did, and now that the urlRoot is set on the model, it should save to your server correctly.

```
// Not sure you want to be setting the ID here in case you want it to 
// be set on the server when it is persisted
var item = new app.models.Item({
    "name": "Gokul"
});
item.save();
```

You can then manually add the item to your collection:

```
items.add(item);
```

Or you can just fetch the items again and it should be there now:

```
items.fetch();
```

Just remember again, the fetch() will only work if you have waited for the item to be saved to the server (asynchronously) first.

Good luck!

Comment: `{async: false}` is a valid option for Backbone `fetch` calls, as are other [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) options. `fetch` delegates to [`Backbone.sync`](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync) which documents this.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. Sorry about that. Still, that's really bad practice as it would lock up the browser during the call.